# One to one relationship for same relationship to different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, doctrine-orm, mysql-workbench

I creating a database in which I have an artefact that can be associated with either a project, production or performance. I will call the relationship 'comes_from'. This relationship can be a project or a more specific version of a project such as a production or performance.

I don't want to have separate foreign keys on my artefact for each possible value of the 'comes_from' relationship as it feels wrong to have multiple attributes for the same relationship. The only way I can think of doing this is having a separate table that stores the comes_from relationship containing the id of the referenced project or more specific version along with the table the item is located in.

```
artefact table
+-------------+------------+
| artefact_id | comes_from | -- Foreign key to comes_from
+-------------+------------+
| 1           | 7          |
| 2           | 8          |
+-------------+------------+

comes_from table
+---------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| comes_from_id | comes_from (FK) | comes_from_table (FK table)     |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+
| 7             | 19              | project                         |
| 8             | 13              | performance                     |
| 9             | 21              | production                      |
+---------------+-----------------+---------------------------------+

project table
+-------------+
| project_id  |
+-------------+
| 19          |
| 20          |
+-------------+

performance table
+-----------------+
| performance_id  |
+-----------------+
| 13              |
| 14              |
+-----------------+

production table
+---------------+
| production_id |
+---------------+
| 21            |
| 22            |
+---------------+
```

Is there a better way to do this as I am not sure I can even resolve this relationship in a SQL query and it may cause issues when I use Doctrine as an ORM on top of this database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good, the "comes_from_table" column could be a simple VARCHAR or INT indexed field acting as a discriminator field. However, I would remove the "comes_from" column from the "artefact" table and the "comes_from_id" column and use directly the "artefact_id" column to reference artefacts in the relationship table.

Regarding Doctrine there shouldn't be any problem, I did something similar in the past using Symfony2 and Doctrine2 for an entity called Tags where a Tag could either belong to a contact or to a contact spouse. I also created a function in the repository file where I could pass the "tag_type" as a parameter so that I could get either the contact or the contact spouse tags.

Comment: That's great, thank you very much. That's a good point about removing the "comes_from" from artefact and re-working it a little. Thanks again.